# How to convert a Tomcat webapp to an Oracle Application Server webapp?

Tags: tomcat, web-deployment-project, oas

I have a webapp that runs perfectly in Apache Tomcat 5.5 and I need to "convert it" so it can be deployed in an Oracle Application Server 10.1.3.

Right now I make a WAR file of the aplication, paste it in the "webapps" directory of the Tomcat installation and then start the service (this works with Windows and Linux). Deploying **the same** WAR file in the Oracle Application Server doesn't work, the server says that the application is up but this message appears when I invoke an application URL:

> 500 Internal Server Error Servlet
>   error: An exception occurred. The
>   current application deployment
>   descriptors do not allow for including
>   it in this response. Please consult
>   the application log for details.

And the application log is empty...

The application was developed in Eclipse with Java 1.6 update 3 and it uses Struts 1, Hibernate, JasperReports and JDBC for the database connection. The web.xml that I'm using is version 2.4.

Anybody knows what changes must I do in order to get it working in OAS?

Comment: Do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing basically means that the server is configured not to include technical error messages and stacktraces in the webpage. This may be done so to avoid leaking sensitive information to the public.

That you're seeing noting in the logs is another problem which you need to fix first. I don't do OAS/OC4J, so I can't go in detail with this, but you likely need to configure its logging. This may be a helpful starting point: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/core.1013/b32196/log.htm

Once you've got the logging right, you'll likely see more clear and helpful debugging/tracking information to nail down the actual problem. Without it, it is hard to tell what's the root cause of your problem. But I will anyway put my cents on sort of a classpath problem :) Good luck and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

@Accollativo Hello there. That was way too long ago, so I hardly remember all the details. What I do remember is that, at that time, you couldn't deploy a WAR file directly in OAS like you do in Tomcat (by copy and pasting a WAR file). Things are (were) a bit more complicated in OAS.

So in order to deploy, we would use some kind of deployment wizard in the OAS admin page. The goal of this wizard was to create an EAR file, that would contain the WAR file that we needed to deploy (the wizard asks for WAR files in one of the steps).

I don't remember all the details, I remember there were a lot of flags that I would turn on and off in the deployment steps. And the values were something we figure out after some trial and errors.

I'm sorry, this was a long time ago.

As far as I remember there was no need to modify the code. It was all about the deployment process.

I would look for a guide for the deployment wizard of your OAS version.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I solved passing from OC4J to weblogic